# Query DynamicFrame in AWS Glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

i have a question about DynamicFrames, i want to run query in the moment when i get data from the catalog and avoid get all the data and then query.
At the moment it's not a lot of data, but maybe in the future.
Now, i testing with the parameter "push_down_predicate", but only run when the data is partitioned.

Example:

```
df_data = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "datalake-raw",
                                                            table_name = "data",
                                                            transformation_ctx = "df_data",
                                                            push_down_predicate = "( CampaignKey == '1')")
```

Know another way to run that? is this possible to do?

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm affraid it will only work on partitioned data indeed. As per the docs: push_down_predicate – Filters partitions without having to list and read all the files in your dataset. There is also this parameter additional_options = {'catalogPartitionPredicate': 'indexed_column') that leverages Glue Partition Index but again, it must be partitioned. There is a  'query' option for additional options but are for Lake Formation tables.